# How detect version of VMProtect

Tags: disassembly, unpacking, packers, vmprotect

I have a binary with [VMProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/). Some tools giving info that this is 2.x, some that 3.x. How I could check it? Thanks.

Comment: Which tools are you using?

Comment: Could you show some disassembly of a vm handler? You can recognize you’re in a vm handler if you step and see a push xxxx; call yyy where yyy is in one of the vmp sections.

Comment: @SYS_V I used Protection ID v6.90.

Comment: @mrexodia at birany only some function at VMProtect and code is long with big cound of jmp something like that:
cmp     [esi+ecx*2+0BAC1C45h], bl
mov     bh, 0EEh
adc     [esi], ebp
pop     esp
mov     eax, ds:5E830102h
db      26h
or      eax, 0BA322563h
xor     [edi], esp
push    eax
rcl     dword ptr [edx], 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy answer here.

Most of these tools employ different types of heuristics to determine the version used. Often times just applying binary signatures which could be inaccurate. Without gaining a decent understanding of VMProtect to recognize the differences this will be quite difficult.

If tools used are open-source or well-documented, you can go over the signature used to detect the version, and validate it manually once you have a good understanding of the rational behind it.